# Efficient way to Add/Update or Delete with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to loop through a series of updates which will either involve adding / updating a record, or removing it. The updates need to be carried out in order, so I couldn't just do a bulk delete at the end.

Is there an efficient / quick way to achieve this through Rails.

Currently I'm envisaging looping through the updates. If it's a delete request, deleting it. If it's not, searching for it. If it exists, updating. If it doesn't, adding.

I don't think, when dealing with thousands of updates, this is going to be very pleasant so I was wondering if there is a more efficient way I could go about this process?

Comment: Could you paste some code so we can see how are you approaching the problem? Also, can you run a test with thousand of records and see if there's a slow down? Maybe your app won't even hit this scenario, so there is no need to make the code more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `destroy_all` `delete_all` `update_all` with conditions/scopes like:

```
User.where(:active => false).destroy_all
```